# Process Purchase Event get called on each App launch - iOS

Tags: unity, in-app-purchase

At present when I launch the app, each time ProcessPurchase event get called in iPhone device. Though upto now I have not pressed any purchase related buttons.

Yes I have setup subscription purchase within my app and before I have purchased subscription in sandbox environment two to three times but now their time period is expired.

Here you have debug log for actual event happening:

[image]

As per my past experience, ProcessPurchase event require to call only two times when a user purchase something or at restore purchase time.

So why its get called each application launch that I can't able to understand!!!

Please give some help in this so I can complete my Unity IAP related thing.

Source Code :
https://pastebin.com/bNpXsjHg

Comment: Please try including things such as *code* or *logs* in code-blocks. This makes them easier to read and also does not prevent people from helping you if they cannot access imgur or have eyesight related problems

Comment: @dot_Sp0T I have integrated complete source code file.